# Перемещение мяча по полю при клике

Tags: javascript

```js
var field = document.getElementById('field');
var ball  = document.getElementById('ball');

field.addEventListener('click', function(e){
  // получаем координаты элемента 
    var fieldСoords = field.getBoundingClientRect();
  // в переменную top получаем координаты верхней линии  + сама верхняя рамка 
    var top = fieldСoords.top + field.clientTop
   // в переменную left получаем координаты левой линии  + сама левая рамка 
    var left = fieldСoords.left + field.clientLeft
  // находим центр мяча
  var ballLeft = ball.clientWidth / 2;
  var ballTop = ball.clientHeight / 2;
  // от ширины экрана отнимаем верхнию рамку
  // e объект события 
  var clinX = e.clientX - left;
  var clinY = e.clientY - top;
  // в конец добавляем единицу измерения в виде строки 
    ball.style.left =  clinX + 'px';
    ball.style.top = clinY + 'px';
});
```

```css
#field {
      width: 200px;
      height: 150px;
      border: 10px groove black;
      background-color: #00FF00;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      cursor: pointer;
      margin: auto;
    }

    #ball {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      -webkit-transition: all 1s;
      -moz-transition: all 1s;
      -o-transition: all 1s;
      -ms-transition: all 1s;
      transition: all 1s;
```

```html
<div id="field">
    <img src="https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg" id="ball" width='40px' height='40px'> . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
  </div>
```

что дает этот кусок кода **e.clientX** ?

Comment: Эмм... а в чем вопрос?

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME инспекция-кода

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME описание js посмотрите правильно я все понял вот вопрос :))

Comment: Метка "инспекция кода" подразумевает, что вы приводите не просто рабочий пример кода, а пример своего кода. Если вы скопипастили откуда-то код, может даже и рабочий - но не понимаете как он работает (я вижу вопрос "что делает этот кусок кода") - то метка инспекция лишняя, вы не ревью запрашиваете. Если вы хотите ревью кода, тогда вопрос выглядит странным.

Comment: @A K хочу уточнить e.clientX это  e это объект документа clientX  получить координаты объекта я тут просто не до конца понял

Comment: Я этот мяч тут уже видел...

Comment: @Qwertiy я читал описание, а потом сам написал js код (не html, css каюсь копипастил) единственное до конца не понял этот код  e.clientX; e - это объект события clientX - это координаты экрана; e.clientX получается координаты события

Comment: @Qwertiy затем мы отнимаем координаты рамки +  саму рамку получается будут координаты поля без рамки

Comment: @Qwertiy т.к.объект это верхний левый угол то надо делить на 2 чтобы получить центр (мяч)

Comment: @Qwertiy получается при клике по полю мяч будет сдвигаться  на половину своей ширины и высоты верно ?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q подскажите зачем от e.clientX - getBoundingClientRect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас `ballTop` и `ballLeft` нигде не используется. Надо поправить так, чтобы мяч вставал ровно по точке клика:

```
 var clinX = e.clientX - left - ballLeft,
   clinY = e.clientY - top - ballTop;
```

И не стоит пистаь каждый раз `var`. Можно объявлять переменные через запятую.